# How to assign new variables during loops?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not a native English speaker, so excuse me if I made some English mistakes.

I am currently working on a Python program and stuck right here. 
This is what my code looks like :

[image]

And you might guess, yes, I am a beginner.

I was trying to make assign new variable student[i], but instead, it gave me an error.

What is the correct way to code to make it work properly?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: post your code, instead of image

Comment: `student` is a `Student` object, that doesn't support indexing like that. What would you expect that to do? Or are you trying to create *a new variable dynamically?* You shouldn't do that. Use a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: You don't define what `student` is.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga How do you know that `student` is an instance of `Student`?

Comment: @Selcuk because of the error message

Answer (score 1):

As your screen, look like you are assigning a `Student` instance to `student` variable so it does not support item assignment `student[i]`.

To fix it you can change it to a list and append to your result.

```py
students = []
i = 0

while i < 4:
   student = Studen(namelist[i], mathlist[i])
   students.append(student)
   i += 1

print(students)
for student in students:
   print(student.name_and_score())
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you defined the class but never instantiated it. It also looks like you're trying to add these `Student` objects to an array, so first of all we add an empty array after declaring mathlist:

```
students = []
```

Then, before proceeding I'd like to clarify something. You seem quite confused about the *scope* of variables. Python defines symbols within a scope: to put it simply, if you declare something in a block it will be visible from that block and any block that's hierarchically inside it, meaning if you define a variable inside the `for` loop, it won't be visible outside it. This doesn't mean changes you do to already declared symbols don't hold true outside a block modifying them, and that's probably why you were pointed towards creating a list and then adding elements to it: the list is declared outside the loop so if you add the `Student` objects to it from inside the loop you'll be able to access them outside too.

That said, inside the first loop just replace

```
student[i]=Students(namelist[i], mathlist[i])
```

with

```
students.add(Student(namelist[i], mathlist[i])
```

and you will have the desired output, with `Student` objects at position `i` of the array having `namelist[i]` and `mathlist[i]` as parameters.

*Note on renamed variables:* I renamed your `Students` class to `Student` because a class generally defines a singular entity, so if I do `peter = Student('Peter', 5)` I can say that `peter` is a `Student`. I renamed the `student` list to `students` because a list is a collection of multiple objects in Python so it's better defined with a plural name in this case.